# In a grid of resistors, does placement of the voltage source affect the nodal resistances?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, resistance

Does the placement of the voltage source affect resistances in nodes in a grid of resistors?

[image]

And if yes, then is there a right way to "generally" analyze the resistances between nodes of such circuit? I.e. without the analysis depending on the voltage source's place, but rather only on the resistors (and location of nodes) themselves. Can one e.g. analyze the resistances of equivalent resistance without considering any particular voltage source?

---

A more simple example:

In this circuit, does the resistance between A and B depend on whether you put the voltage source to come in at A and leave at B?

[image]

---

Some methods for solving these problems are given here:
http://www.rfcafe.com/miscellany/factoids/kirts-cogitations-256.htm

Comment: Are you asking whether the individual resistances will vary, or whether the effective load resistance seen by the voltage source will vary?

Comment: @Justin Whether resistances in nodes and between nodes will vary.

Comment: Plug it into a sim and find out, then you can tell us.

Comment: How could the placement of a voltage source change the value of a resistor? If you put a 5kOhm resistor somewhere, it doesn't change its value because you moved a voltage source. Now, if you're asking whether it will change the *equivalent* resistance seen from two points, I'd tell you that if there is a voltage source anywhere in this circuit, then you can't reduce it to a simple resistor between these two points, anyway. So either I don't understand the question, or there is no point in this question.

Comment: @dim I'm probably asking about equivalent resistance, but am very new to circuit analysis.

Comment: [Relevant Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/on-this-infinite-grid-of-resistors-whats-the-equivalent-resistance), and, as always, [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/356/)

Comment: You question is unclear. For example, if you are to calculate the Thevinin equivalent resistance between any two points, placing a voltage source in the circuit would definitely change that. If you want the Thevenin resistance between A and B and you put a voltage source at A and B, since a voltage source has zero resistance, it totally dominates and you get zero resistance.

Comment: @rioraxe I don't know. This seems to be a pretty typical problem in one form or another: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/equivalent-resistance-geometric-resistor-network.342148/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/how-calculate-resistance-between-two-points-for-arbitrary-resistor-grid etc.

Comment: The answer in your link show a method of calculating the resistance by introducing a fictitious current source. It is different from how you worded many of your questions. If your question is: Can you introduce a fictitious voltage source at point A-B as an aid to calculate the equivalent resistance at point A-B? The answer is yes.

Comment: If there is a resistor, I can apply a voltage source, measure the current, and deduce the resistance of the resistor. But the resistance of circuit with the voltage source attached is different from the resistor all alone.

Comment: @rioraxe So they are two different things? How does one calculate resistances without a fictitious current source?

Comment: Neil_UK has shown one way. Another way is perhaps what you were really asking all along. Apply a voltage source at A-B. Then use any method (nodal or mesh for example) to calculate the current coming out of the voltage source. The original resistance at A-B (not including the voltage source) is simply V/I = R, the ohm's law. (This is similar to how a real ohm meter measures resistance.)

Answer (score 2):

For a network of constant voltage independent resistors, any given pair of nodes will have a defined resistance between them, which can be calculated from the values and connections of the resistors making up the network.

Generally the resistance between any two nodes will be different to any other two. In the case of a symmetrical network, any symmetrically placed pairs will show the same resistance.

If a voltage source is connected between any two nodes, the current that flows through it will be given by the voltage, and the resistance that the network offers between those two nodes.

If you connect a second voltage source somewhere else, the current that flows in each will not be the same as if they were the only source connected, as a voltage source has a zero output resistance, which will change the topology of the resistor network.

In both the large and small networks you have shown, the resistance is entirely calculable from the resistor values. I will do it for the small network. The large network takes longer, but the only difference is scale, not whether it can be done. If you do this, I recommend arithmetic, algebra will get very cumbersome very fast. Symmetrical networks will be quicker as you can take short cuts, but the technique works for all general networks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTeWOq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To find the resistance between nodes A and B. Notice that R1 and R7 are in series, so combine them at R54, similarly for R6 and R13, which go to R55.

Now take the triangle of R27, R35, R54, and do a star-delta transform on them to get the star of R44, R53, and R38. Similarly take R55, R36, R30, and transform them into R49, R43 and R52.

Now we have R44 and R45 in series, add them in series to get R61. Similarly we absorb the other pairs of series resistors into single resistors.

Nearly done. I'm not going to illustrate the rest of it as you can see which way the wind is blowing. Iterate through the network, adding series resistors, and using the star-delta transform to put resistors in series when they aren't. So take the delta of R64, R61 and R57 and flip it to a star, then two of the star legs will be in series with R58 and R62, and keep going until it's one resistor.

Repeat for each other pair of nodes that interests you.

The comment above by Jim 'plug it into a sim and find out' was not as facetious as it sounds. If you found the component-wise reduction above tedious, that's because as a human, it is. I was studying the topology to look for short cuts to minimise the number of calculations. Similarly if I were solving a pair of simultaneous equations, I would notice common factors, take advantage of zero or unity coefficients for instance. A computer program OTOH would simply fill out the large regular matrix in both cases, and flog through it. Far simpler topology, though more calculations.

Comment: But what about the location of the voltage source? Does it affect the resistances between nodes?

Comment: which bit of 'any given pair of nodes will have a defined resistance between them, which can be calculated from the values and connections of the resistors making up the network' didn't you understand? When you add a voltage source, you get to be able to measure that resistance, if you can measure the current flowing from the voltage source.

Comment: Okay, so how do you calculate the equivalent resistance between two nodes without considering any particular voltage source or its location?

Comment: @mavavilj edited answer to show explicitly

Comment: Is the method you present the only method? I kind of liked the fictitious voltage source approach because it uses very simple algebra and only KCL and Ohm's law. But do e.g. these two give the same answer?

Comment: @mavavilj It's **a** method that gives the same result as any other valid method. If you'd asked something more analytically interesting like the conductance at any node into a grid of equal resistors with a ground at infinity, or on a regular rectangular grid, then you could invoke current sources, in regular arrays to create the boundary conditions, and use superposition to then get the conductance between nodes. But voltage sources are zero impedance, so they don't work as nicely. Perhaps you'd run through the fictitious voltage source derivation, edit it into your question, or link to it?

Comment: OK, the resistor cube you linked to relies on the symmetry for the shortcuts. What's the fictitious voltage source method?

Comment: What a splendidly nice illustration of simplifying networks.